# trying to install python-igraph on chaquopy android studio

Tags: python, android-studio, gradle, igraph, chaquopy

I'm trying to do some image processing on my android stuio app with python. I'm using Chaquopy and the python script requires igraph import. But when I'm trying to install python-igraph in build.gradle(app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.chaquo.python'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chaq"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }

        python {
            buildPython "C:/Users/shani/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe"
            pip{
                install "opencv-contrib-python-headless"
                install "pillow"
                install "numpy"
                install "python-igraph"
            }
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                python.srcDir "src/main/python"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

the sync works fine but then when I try to run the app on the simulator the build fails (I'm using at the moment a mock script that doesn't require igraph).

Here is the error:
igraph uses CMake as the build system. You need to install CMake before compiling igraph.
Build failed for the C core of igraph.

this is my build.gradle(chaq) file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://chaquo.com/maven" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1"
        classpath "com.chaquo.python:gradle:9.1.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How do I install this Cmake?

Comment: Unfortunately this package isn't available for Chaquopy yet, and installing CMake won't make any difference in this case. To be notified if we add it in the future, please subscribe to [this issue](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/539).